# Symfony Routing `options` Configuration Key

Tags: php, symfony, routes

If I enter in an invalid routing configuration key in a Symfony route, I get a helpful exception message that lists all the valid Symfony routing configuration keys

> The routing file "path/to/config/routes.yaml" contains unsupported keys for "route_name": "invalid_key_name". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition", "controller", "name_prefix", "trailing_slash_on_root"

Most of these keys are documented somewhere on [the Symfony site](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).  However, I have not been able to find documentation for the `options` key.

Does anyone know what this should (or can) be used for?

Comment: I think it does as the name says on the tin - an options-type array.. basing assumption (hence, no answer) on: https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.html (skip down to Route: getOptions/setOptions)

Comment: +1 Useful bit of knowedge @treyBake, thank you!  I'm hoping someone with deeper symfony experience than either of us can explain what these options are used for, of if this is just a way to set options that you might fetch later via PHP code.

Comment: No worries, glad I can help out a vet such as yourself :) I think it's the latter but without fully knowing, I can't speak in absolutes :S however, if someone does come along, let me know, be interested in seeing the answer :)

Comment: I found one use case in the documentation where `options` is used to support UTF-8 characters in the route paths, see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html#unicode-routing-support).

Comment: Until <3.4 the option param was used to define, as example, the utf8 parameter while from >=4.x the [utf8 param have its own definition](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#utf8). I guess that the option param was leaved there mostly for compatibility reasons present in the 3.4 version.

Comment: Sorry, only from 4.2 the utf8 param have its own definition. I entrusted myself too much to my memory :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into a route object's class file reveals this

```
#File: vendor/symfony/routing/Route.php
public function setOptions(array $options)
{
    $this->options = array(
        'compiler_class' => 'Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\RouteCompiler',
    );

    return $this->addOptions($options);
}
```

That is -- Symfony sets a `compiler_class` field on the options array, and it's this options array that the `options:` configuration key is linked to.   Symfony then uses this compiler class option in the same class

```
#File: vendor/symfony/routing/Route.php
public function compile()
{
    if (null !== $this->compiled) {
        return $this->compiled;
    }

    $class = $this->getOption('compiler_class');

    return $this->compiled = $class::compile($this);
}
```

So -- probably not something 99% of Symfony devs will need/want to use, but it is still there.